# Addition of two variables in selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I have store one value in one variable and second in other, now i want to make addition of those two number.I am not able to do that, I have  tried below code but its not working

```
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>w</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>x</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>javascript{storedVars['w'] + storedVars['x']}</td>
    <td>z</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${z}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Next time you ask a question, "it is not working" is a pretty poor statement of your problem.  Consider showing what you get, what error it displays, *etc.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to use `storeEval` command

```
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>${w}+${x}</td>
    <td>z</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: For me worked this way: <td>storedVars['w']+storedVars['x']</td>

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to add quotes around the variables...

So:

```
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>&quot;${w}&quot;+&quot;${x}&quot;</td>
    <td>z</td>
</tr>
```

You might see some annoying semi-colon related errors if you don't! 
Cheers!